# Is the operator $Tf = f(x) - f(x) \int_0^1 f(y) dy$ a contraction?

Tags: functional-analysis, fixed-point-theorems, contraction-operator

Is the operator $$Tf = f(x) - f(x) \int_0^1 f(y) dy$$ in $C[0,1]$ (with the uniform norm)  a contraction and what is the possible fixed point?

Comment: Is the space $C([0,1])$ endowed with the supremum norm?

Comment: By definition, the zero function $x \mapsto 0$ is a fixed point of $T$.

Comment: @blux In order to avoid downvotes you should write the question together with your thoughts!

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, I'll bear that in mind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint 1. Note that $Tf=f$ if and only if $f(x) \int_0^1 f(y) dy=0$ for all $x\in [0,1]$.

Hint 2. We have that
$$|(Tf)(x)|=
|f(x) - f(x) \int_0^1 f(y) dy|=|f(x)|\left|1-\int_0^1 f(y) dy\right|$$
so, for example, if $f=3$ and $g=0$ then 
$$\|(Tf)-(Tg)\|=\left|1-3\right|\|f-g\|=2\|f-g\|$$
where $\|\cdot\|$ is the uniform norm in $C[0,1]$.

Hint 3. Is $T$ a contraction in the closed ball $\{f\in C[0,1]: \|f\|\leq r \}$ for some $r>0$?

Comment: Following the answer of Robert Z, the function $f(x) := \sin(2 \pi x)$ is also a fixed point of the operator $T$.